# how to call wpf user control from winform

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a winform 'form1' and a wpf usercontrol 'wpfuser1'

I set 'wpf user1' as a splash screen with progress bar

in form1 I would like to call that splash screen to indicate the form is loading.

How can I do that in form1?

```
public Form1()
    {
        this.Hide();

        UserControl1 wpfuser1 = new UserControl1();

        //wpfuser1.show() ?????

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        this.Visible = true;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ElementHost control. See this link for help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx